# If a string after the last slash of a URL exists, capture the value; if not, capture the value before the last slash (javascript)

Tags: javascript, substring

I'm wanting to be able to capture the usernames of users Facebook profiles and I know that's super easy to do when the URL looks like this:

`https://www.facebook.com/123456`

All I have to do is this:

```
var str = "foo/bar/test.html";
var n = str.lastIndexOf('/');
var result = str.substring(n + 1);
// Result == '123456'
```

But if the URL looks like this:

`https://www.facebook.com/123456/`

The JS above returns an empty string. So how can I:

- The get the value after the last slash (/) unless the value is empty
- **If** the value is empty, get the value before the last slash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var result = str.split("/").filter(Boolean).pop();
```

Comment: Oh wow that works amazingly well. Is there any way you could explain what's happening?

Comment: @LaurenEccles Split string at `/` charcaters, if last character at `str` is `/`, `.split()` sets last index of resulting array to empty string `""` which `.filter()` with parameter `Boolean` removes from filtered array, as empty string `""` returns a "falsey" value; or `""` is equated as `false` at `.filter()`. If last character of `str` is not `/` the last index should be portion of string following last `/` character in string. `.pop()` returns last index of an array, providing same result if last character in `str` is `/` or is not `/`.